# How can I refactor a `for` loop?

Tags: java

#### Problem

I want to be able to split up a `for` loop into a method, then put the `for` the method in the `for` loop to make it easier to read. Below demonstrates this:

#### Example.java

```
for(int member = firstMember; member < arrayOfMembers.length; member++) {
    [...] other code
}
```

Should be refactored to:

#### Solution Example:

```
private boolean eachMemberInList() {
       return int member = firstMember; member < arrayOfMembers.length; member++);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(eachMemberInList());
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How is that easier to read?

Comment: I find that explicitly writing what the code is doing in the loop, can make you understand more quickly what the code is doing.

Comment: I agree with @CrisCM but you could do some thing like that with a while loop, having member and arrayOfMembers as fields

Comment: I would highly suggest you not doing this.

Comment: If you weren't using an array it's arguably easier to read when using a collection and doing, FE, `list.forEach(x -> { ... });`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot return or otherwise manipulate a `for` loop as if it were an object in Java.

However, what you're attempting to do is unnecessary.  You can use an array directly in an ["enhanced" `for` loop, since Java 1.5](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).

```
for (int member : arrayOfMembers) { ... }
```

It is more concise than attempting to create a method to manipulate a `for` loop, and it is even more concise than the standard `for` loop you're attempting to replace.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is turning a for loop, into a while loop.

```
for (; true; )
```

is equivalent to

```
while (true)
```

So, you're solution could be viewed as

```
while (someFunctionIsTrue()) {}
```

Don't want to get into religious debates here, but generally, if you're iterating over an array of objects, you really do want to use a for lop.  Not necessarily because it's any different than a while loop using your solution, but because it's idiomatic.  When a developer (an experienced developer) sees a for loop, the fact that you chose a for loop tells them something.  It says, hey, I'm iterating over the objects of a container.  What a while loop says, is that there is some condition, and while that condition is true do something.

While loops and for loops are identically in capability.  By using them idiomatically, you can communicate your code more concisely and clearly.  For example:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < array.size) {
    doSomethingWithArrayElement(array[index]);
    index++;
}
```

This is not concise.  The hanging variable declaration creates an extra line of code, as does the index++ at the end.  When you do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
   doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

This is very concise, and your use of a for loop... if used concistently like this, immediately tells a developer that all items of this container are going to have something done with them!

Now let's use the alternate example, where we have a function that returns a boolean.  And this boolean tells the loop whether to continue or not.  We could do something like this:

```
int index = 0;
for (; doSomethingWithArrayItem(array, index); index++){
}

boolean doSomethingWithArrayItem(array, index) {
    //blah blah blah
    if (index + 1 == array.size) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This accomplishes what you want, but is difficult logic to follow.  Let's say that you named your doSomething function something useful, like

```
incrementValueByTwo(item);
```

What do you think this function does?  It's pretty clear right.  Now, let's place this function in the for loop above:

```
int index = 0;
    for (; incrementValueByTwo(array, index); index++){
}
```

How many values are we incrementing?  Are we incrementing all the values of the array by 2?  Some of them?  The first one?  Or perhaps none of them under certain circumstances?  THIS IS VERY CONFUSING!!!!  DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: I was told that we use a `for` loop when we know exactly when the loop will end; and a `while` loop when we do not know when it ends. Would you agree with this?

Comment: What you just said, is a more concise way of saying what I said, and extending it to a few other scenarios, that are more difficult to create examples for :).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do something like

```
String[] array = new String[10];

for(String variable : array){
     doSomething(variable);
}
```

Or if you are using Java 8 then

```
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(memberOfArray -> doSomething(memberOfArray));
```

This is much more readable.